# Netbeanss Java Web Application not running when in a Repository

Tags: git, netbeans, web-applications, glassfish, bitbucket

When creating java web application projects in Netbeans, I can run them just fine. I would like to back up all my projects in a repository (Bitbucket). Whenever I move the projects into another folder (via Netbeans UI) and make that a git repository, Netbeans will not deploy my project on the Glassfish Web Server. The project can be clean and built just fine, but for some reason will not be deployed.

I assume this has to do with project properties and the project not being where it used to be, but I figured if I made the move through Netbeans, those properties would update. Can anyone give me some clarification on what I am doing wrong or if anyone else has this situation?

Comment: Why are you moving the projects before initialising a git repository? Can't you `git init` each project in turn from where they are? If you're set on doing things the way you are, you will need to upload some error logs from GlassFish if we're to have any chance of helping.

Comment: I successfully got around this issue by initializing the repository through the IDE (previously was doing it by SourceTree). I was able to commit my code and build and run with no errors.